# Warning: implode()

Tags: php, loops, implode

I recieved the following warning:

> Warning: implode() [function.implode]: Invalid arguments passed.

What caused this and how can I fix it?

```
$title = $_POST[photo_name_id];
if($title)
{
    foreach($title as $titled)
    {
        $judul[] = $titled;
    }
}

$titleds = "('".implode("'), ('",$judul)."')";
```

and this is my form:

```
<tr>
    <td> 
        <?  
        $pm1= mysql_query("SELECT photo_name FROM photo_name WHERE photo_name_id = 1");
        $dpm1 = mysql_fetch_array ($pm1);echo"$dpm1[0]"
        ?> 
        <input type='hidden' name='photo_name_id[]' value='<?echo"$dpm1[0]"?>'> :  
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td> 
        <?  
        $pm1= mysql_query("SELECT photo_name FROM photo_name WHERE photo_name_id = 2");
        $dpm1 = mysql_fetch_array ($pm1);echo"$dpm1[0]"
        ?>
        <input type='hidden' name='photo_name_id[]' value='<?echo"$dpm1[0]"?>'> :  
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Obviously `$judul` is not an array, which means `$title` evaluates to `false`. Find out why. (Also, what's the point of making `$judul` a copy of `$title`? You already have the original!)

Comment: @mikeymeows thanks for the feedback and edit my question mikeymeows. You are right and i still learning in php and sory for my english

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens if `$title` evaluates to false? Then your if statement won't execute and the array won't be created. `implode()` will complain with a warning because an unset variable is passed in. It wanted an array.

You should either initialize `$judul` to an empty array or place the implode in your if.

Also, quote your array keys. It's bad practice not to, because initially PHP assumes they are constants.

```
$title = $_POST['photo_name_id'];
if($title) {
    foreach($title as $titled) {
            $judul[] = $titled;
    }

    $titleds = "('" . implode("'), ('", $judul) . "')";
}
```

Or this (more preferable, because `$titleds` will always be set):

```
$title = $_POST['photo_name_id'];
$judul = array();

if($title) {
    foreach($title as $titled) {
            $judul[] = $titled;
    }
}

$titleds = "('" . implode("'), ('", $judul) . "')";
```

However this all prompts the question. Why are you copying `$title` into a new array. Why not just do:

```
$title = $_POST['photo_name_id'];

if(!is_array($title)) {
    $title = array();
}

$titleds = "('" . implode("'), ('", $title) . "')";
```

Comment: i m just a newbie man.. i m still learning... heheheh thanks for the feedback

Comment: @MeijuNainggolan Basically if you replace your current code with the last code block everything should work with no warnings.

Comment: @MeijuNainggolan No problem. Welcome to SO!

Comment: i want to know if i have multiple string and i want to looping them all can i do like this ?  sorry man i dunno how to paste the code in here

Comment: @MeijuNainggolan From the looks of it, that doesn't look right. You can't use commas in an if expression like that. You should create a new question for this!

Answer (score 4):

Try to add :

```
$judul = array();
```

Before to initialize `$judul` as an `array`.

```
$judul = array();

$title = $_POST[photo_name_id];
if($title)
{
    foreach($title as $titled)
    {
        $judul[] = $titled;

    }
}

$titleds = "('".implode("'), ('",$judul)."')";
```

Comment: With your optimized code, if `$title` is not an array it will still a warning. Also, you have a typo. You typed `$titled` instead of `$title`.

Comment: @Aelios You didn't. On the first line of your optimized code you set the variable `$title`. On the fourth line you use the variable `$titled` which is not set within your snippet. Essentially you'll get the same warning that the OP had before

Comment: @Aelios You don't have to remove it. Just fix that typo! :P

Answer (score -1):

Make sure `$judul` is an array. PHP implode needs parameters (string, array). See [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php).